# exiting a game in unity after a certain score is reached

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity which is started by a button click on Windows Form Application and I want to close the game and return to the form when the score equals to 18. My current code does not quit the game upon reaching that score.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public Text scoretext;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoretext.text = Player.position.z.ToString("0");
        if (scoretext.text == "18")
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: the part where you close the game with a certain highscore IMO is to be handled on the game-side. On the winforms side, you may for instance continuously monitor if the game (a child process) is still open.

Comment: In any case, the question as standing is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. It's unlikely that someone will create a step by step full tutorial for you, and it's not clear where you are stuck exactly.

Comment: In general from a user perspective: **Why** should you ever want to do this? I would rather make some kind of game over scene/screen .. but simply exiting the game if your score reaches a certain value sounds like a very bad move :D

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide much informations, however, as @Pac0 said, you have to close the game "game-side".

In Unity, you can handle creating a C# Script component which check the score and close the game:

```
if(score > highscore){
   Application.Quit();
}
```

The script has to be attached to an active GameObject at the end of the "match".

The highscore can be saved inside Unity with `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore",highscore)` and read with `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore",0)`.